# Don't bring up the flag resolution dialog when clicking on a link in the flag text

Tags: bug, flags, user-interface, moderator-tools

When browsing a post with a pending flag as a moderator, a footer appears with details about the flag. Clicking on the flag text brings up the flag resolution dialog (which can also be reached by clicking the “no action needed…” button).

If the flag text contains a hyperlink, the hyperlink is rendered in blue. Left-clicking on the link briefly shows the flag resolution dialog while the browser is loading the linked page. Middle-clicking on the link both shows the flag resolution dialog and opens the linked page in a new tab.

Please fix the interface so that clicking on a hyperlink in the flag text doesn't have both effects. At least a middle click on a link should not bring up the flag resolution dialog (for a left click, it's more cosmetic).

Comment: Probably gonna drop that UI for flags entirely in the near future; flag-clicking was just a stop-gap.